# draw flot graph with bar and line

Tags: jquery, graph, bar-chart, flot, linegraph

I am trying to create a bar graph with a target line, using flot and jQuery.

The target remains the same each month, while the data moves up and down. I can create the bars without issue but I can't get the line to display. I'm not sure what I'm missing

I've uploaded the code which is causing me issue here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bigbadbaboonboy/r7j0k9gz/

```
<div id="risla-graph" class="graph"></div>

#risla-graph {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
width: 80%;
height: 400px;
}

var datasets = [{"label":"ALL RiSLA","data":[{"0":1451606400000,"1":73.83},
{"0":1454284800000,"1":69.21},{"0":1456790400000,"1":88.33},
{"0":1459465200000,"1":85.99},{"0":1462057200000,"1":82.32},
{"0":1464735600000,"1":0}],"series":{"lines":{"show":false}},"idx":0},
{"label":"Target","color":"#006E2E","data":[{"0":1451606400000,"1":92},
{"0":1454284800000,"1":92},{"0":1456790400000,"1":92},
{"0":1459465200000,"1":92},{"0":1462057200000,"1":92},
{"0":1464735600000,"1":0}],"series":{"lines":
{"show":true,"steps":true,"linewidth":1}},"bars":{"show":false},"legend":
{"show":false},"idx":1}];

var options = {"series":{"stack":0,"lines":
{"show":false,"steps":false},"bars":{"show":true,"fill":1,"align":"center"
,"lineWidth":0,"barWidth":518400000.0000001}}
,"xaxis":{"mode":"time","timeformat":"%b %y"
,"tickSize":[1,"month"]},"yaxis":{"min":64.21,"max":97}
,"grid":{"clickable":true,"hoverable":true},"legend":{"show":false}};

plot = $.plot($('#risla-graph'),  datasets, options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `datasets` array you're enclosing your `lines` options in a `series` object.

```
series: {
    lines: {
        show: true,
        steps: true,
        linewidth:1
    }
}
```

The correct way to specify options for lines in the data object is without the `series` object (per [Flot's api.md](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format)):

```
{
    color: color or number
    data: rawdata
    label: string
    lines: specific lines options
    bars: specific bars options
    points: specific points options
    xaxis: number
    yaxis: number
    clickable: boolean
    hoverable: boolean
    shadowSize: number
    highlightColor: color or number
}
```

I've updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7j0k9gz/1/) to work.

Comment: Thank you. Taking out series helped bring up the target line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
"lines": {"show": false, "steps": false}
```

from your `options`.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7j0k9gz/2/).

Comment: Thank you. This worked too, though i needed the line to step, so I used mechenbier's solution.